# Find a text pattern in excel and delete that row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a list of file names in my spreadsheet and am trying to search for _v1 or _v2 or _v3 etc which is found at the end of the file name but before the file type extension.

Eg File_v1.pdf, file_v22.wav

The number after the v can go all the way up to 99 but The pattern will always be _v#. (Underscore v number period).If the file name contains _v1 etc, then I want to delete that row  Here's the code I'm currently using but using the ? will delete any character.  I'm hoping I don't have to write out _v1. _v2. - 99 times.  Thanks for any help

```
Sub Delete_Version()
Dim c As range, i As Long
Dim SrchRng

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.range("a:a", ActiveSheet.range("a:a").End(xlUp))

For i = 1 To 2

Do

xfind = Choose(i, "_v?.", "_v??.")

Set c = SrchRng.Find(xfind, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Would it be Okay to look for **_V** instead ??

Comment: Your code is working properly,,, and `"_v?.", "_v??."` deletes any name has `_v`, and followed by ANY one or two character/characters, since wildcard `?`   & `??` properly considering all those, whether are `_v1` to `_v99` .

Answer (score 0):

So your question is how to eliminate false positives where eg. _vabc occurs instead of a number?

Excel VBA has evolved its wildcard support over the years. Not sure if the # and or option brackets will work in the find instruction (_v# or _v[0123456789]). It may well depend on the excel version... perhaps.

Worst case you can use the like operator and loop through every row. Worst worst case add the regex object to your project and use regular expressions to find only numerics.